# Object reference not set to an instance of an object using ( READTOEND)

Tags: c#

I have the following code to download the txt file using ftp and write back to another file.

```
 ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpHost + ftpDIR + "/SAPValidObjects.txt");
 ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
 ftp.UseBinary = false;
 ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPWD);
 FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
 Stream sResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader srSAPCostObjects = new StreamReader(sResponse);
 m_swSAPCostCentres.Write(srSAPCostObjects.ReadToEnd());
 m_swSAPCostCentres.Close();
 response.Close();

 m_swSAPCostCentres = new StreamWriter(Properties.Settings.Default.SAPInt + @"\SAPCostCentres" + ".txt");
```

In some reason it throws exception at

```
 m_swSAPCostCentres.Write(srSAPCostObjects.ReadToEnd());
```

Am not sure why,some one please guide me.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders, actually the problem is not there,it causing at other place,am just re modify my question here,thanks for your suggestion

Comment: FYI, your `Stream`, `StreamWriter`, etc. need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Any time you ask about an exception it is pretty important to tell us what the exception is.

Comment: Thanks all guys, just added all your suggestion now its throwing an excption "The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is that the file you are trying to write already exists and is opened by another application.

try to delete the file:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SAPInt + @"\SAPCostCentres" + ".txt"
```

if it exists, before trying to create it again.

in your code you should also add a try catch and make sure you either use using statement to wrap disposable objects or call the close method in the catch or finally block so that streams and other objects are always closed.

Comment: Thanks @Davide Piras, i tried your option too, deleted the file and re run it,now its throwing "The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation."

Comment: Thanks @Davide Piras, i was using stream writer before the ftp and am not use "Using" also,that's why i have that error before,thanks to guide me.now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

> It may be a `typo` but you're `initializing` the `m_swSAPCostCentres`
>   after you're referencing it. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: he is not referencing the object m_swSAPCostCentres before its assignment, and the error of File already in use surely is not because of this, most likely the file is opened in another thread or application or process in his system.

Comment: @DavidePiras I have to correct you (on comment on my answer) - **that was `edited in' at a later date - I couldn't have known that, did I :)**